# Integrity constraint violation when reindexing after migration to Magento 2.3.5-p1

Tags: data-migration-tool, magento2.3.5-p1

We are testing the migration of a store from Magento 1.9.4.5 to 2.3.5-p1 using the Magento Data Migration Tool (version 2.3.5).

The migration completes without issue, however when reindexing on the new M2 site we get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '487-0-3-4-8' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp` AS `i`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `parent_product` ON parent_product.entity_id = i.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_option` AS `bo` ON bo.parent_id = parent_product.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_selection` AS `bs` ON bs.option_id = bo.option_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price` AS `bsp` ON bs.selection_id = bsp.selection_id AND bsp.website_id = i.website_id
SET `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`entity_id` = `i`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`customer_group_id` = `i`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`website_id` = `i`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`option_id` = `bo`.`option_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`selection_id` = `bs`.`selection_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`group_type` = IF(bo.type = 'select' OR bo.type = 'radio', 0, 1), `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`is_required` = `bo`.`required`, `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`price` = LEAST(IF(bsp.selection_price_type = 1, ROUND(i.price * (bsp.selection_price_value / 100),4), IF(i.special_price > 0 AND i.special_price < 100, ROUND(bsp.selection_price_value * (i.special_price / 100),4), bsp.selection_price_value))* bs.selection_qty, IFNULL((IF(i.base_tier IS NOT NULL, IF(bsp.selection_price_type = 1, ROUND(i.base_tier - (i.base_tier * (bsp.selection_price_value / 100)),4), IF(i.tier_percent > 0, ROUND((1 - i.tier_percent / 100) * bsp.selection_price_value,4), bsp.selection_price_value)) * bs.selection_qty, NULL)), IF(bsp.selection_price_type = 1, ROUND(i.price * (bsp.selection_price_value / 100),4), IF(i.special_price > 0 AND i.special_price < 100, ROUND(bsp.selection_price_value * (i.special_price / 100),4), bsp.selection_price_value))* bs.selection_qty)), `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`.`tier_price` = IF(i.base_tier IS NOT NULL, IF(bsp.selection_price_type = 1, ROUND(i.base_tier - (i.base_tier * (bsp.selection_price_value / 100)),4), IF(i.tier_percent > 0, ROUND((1 - i.tier_percent / 100) * bsp.selection_price_value,4), bsp.selection_price_value)) * bs.selection_qty, NULL)
WHERE (i.price_type=1)
```

This error occurs every time we reindex either manually via the CLI or via cron.

How do we troubleshoot and fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The short and handy solution is to fix it directly in the core, in

```
vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/ResourceModel/Indexer/Price.php
```

by going to the function **applyFixedBundleSelectionPrice()** and replace its last line

`$connection->query($query);`

with

```
$connection->query(str_replace("UPDATE", "UPDATE IGNORE",$query));
```

The longer and correct way to go about it is to overwrite the model in a custom module with preference or with a plugin.